# Returning a custom HTTP response code when the authentication fails for a custom basic auth provider

Tags: c#, servicestack

I know that I can return a custom reponse when using a custom authentication provider like the code below:

Return a custom auth response object from ServiceStack authentication

I'm just wondering if there is a way to return a custom HTTP response code.

For example, when the authentication fails, instead of a 401 unauthorized error, I want to send another HTTP response code to give more details on what failed. For example, when the account got locked, I will send the error code XYZ!

```
public class MyBasicAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    public override object Authenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Auth request)
    {
        //let normal authentication happen
        var authResponse = (AuthResponse)base.Authenticate(authService, session, request);

        //return your own class, but take neccessary data from AuthResponse
        return new
            {
                UserName = authResponse.UserName,
                SessionId = authResponse.SessionId,
                ReferrerUrl = authResponse.ReferrerUrl,
                SessionExpires = DateTime.Now
            };

    }
}
```

In a try catch, I found a way of return a custom HTTP code in that function. I return for example:

```
return new ServiceStack.HttpError(423, "Locked");
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way

Comment: You can do it, but the status 423 uses for other cases. 401 status is right for this case. If you want to provide more information to your response, create a custom response with a body. Just as example https://nordicapis.com/best-practices-api-error-handling/ . If you don't know how to do it, it depends on what .net framework or .net core are you using. The solution in middleware/filters. If you need help with it, I can write an answer with examples.

Comment: @Che that's what I did, I created a custom response but Servicestack is still sending the 401 status event if I send 423. It is overwritten somewhere and I don't where and if it is break something.

Comment: Okay, I got you. Can you debug it? Are you sure you got into your line 'return new ServiceStack.HttpError(423, "Locked")'?

Comment: @Che yes I debugged and it was returned correctly. Even with a restlet client the return code is still 401.

Answer (score 2):

The `BasicAuthProvider` is an [IAuthWithRequest Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) that enables [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) where it authenticates when calling a Service, i.e. it does not authenticate using an explicit request to ServiceStack's `/auth` endpoint.

For failed Basic Auth requests you want to return ServiceStack's `401 Unauthorized` Status response with the `WWW-Authenticate` HTTP Header which is required for HTTP Clients to know to prompt for credentials.

I'd recommend against using a different Error Response, but if you really want to customize the Failed Response for HTTP Basic Auth requests you can [override OnFailedAuthentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/105df6748cc68de55004eee0e20a76af182387c0/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L302-L307) in your `BasicAuthProvider` to write the custom Error Response you want:

```
public virtual Task OnFailedAuthentication(IAuthSession session, IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes)
{
    httpRes.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "{0} realm=\"{1}\"".Fmt(this.Provider, this.AuthRealm));
    return HostContext.AppHost.HandleShortCircuitedErrors(httpReq, httpRes, httpReq.Dto);
}
```